# Doctrine UniqueEntity doesn't work

Tags: symfony, doctrine, unique-constraint

I have an invoices table. In this table I have :

1- `invoice_id` column which is `PRIMARY KEY` and `auto_increment`.

2- `invoice_number` column which is unique in the DB.

In my Entity I have this code

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * Invoices
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="invoices", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="invoice_number", columns={"invoice_number"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 *
 *  @UniqueEntity(fields="invoiceNumber", message="invoice number is already exist")
 */
class Invoices
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="invoice_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $invoiceId;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="invoice_number", type="string", length=50, nullable=true, unique=true)
     */
    private $invoiceNumber;
```

In the controller I use `$form->isValid()` like this

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

}
```

I render the field by this code

```
{{ form_label(form.salesInvoice.invoice.invoiceNumber, null, {'label_attr':{'class':'black'}}) }} <span class="required">*</span>
{{ form_widget(form.salesInvoice.invoice.invoiceNumber) }}
<div class="required"> {{ form_errors(form.salesInvoice.invoice.invoiceNumber) }}</div>
```

When I try to save an invoice with duplicate invoice_number I have this error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1230008' for key 'invoice_number'
```

It should not try to save but show a validate message

> invoice number is already exist

Comment: This looks fine... any more relevant info? Are you setting the number though a regular input, or is there more to it? Do other validation constraints work in the project?

Comment: I edit the question adding rendering code. Yes, other validation constraints work well.

Comment: What about changing it from Entity member name `invoiceNumber` to the DB field name `invoice_number`?

Comment: You are talking to the MySQL directly why don't you make a validation in your controller, `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1230008' for key 'invoice_number'` this is a MySQL response, you need to make validation in you controller.

Comment: @YousefAltaf I'm already done and it doesn't work.

Comment: @AndrewNolan I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I'm concerned, the property `fields` in the `UniqueEntity` annotation should be an array, so:

```
@UniqueEntity(fields={"invoiceNumber"}, message="invoice number is already exist")
```

Instead of:

```
@UniqueEntity(fields="invoiceNumber", message="invoice number is already exist")
```

That should do.

Comment: That was first instinct too, but tried it and works both ways. (At least in 4.1)

Comment: Apparently pretty much from day 1 https://github.com/symfony/symfony/commit/23cf63d7673eb48453ef4d8eb0e05e2d747ce7ea.

Comment: Dump something to the `validate` method of `Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntityValidator` to see if reaches there.

Comment: I'm already trying this. @MatíasNavarroCarter I try `@UniqueEntity(fields={"invoiceNumber"})` , `@UniqueEntity(fields="invoiceNumber")` and, `@UniqueEntity("invoiceNumber")`

Comment: @MohammedZayan does others constraint work ? Maybe you don't have enable annotation as they are not enable by default. https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#configuration